# Android mobile app using reCaptcha: why bother?

Tags: android, mobile, bots, recaptcha

I'm developing an Android app and would like to understand if/why I need some facility like [reCaptcha](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha.html). Are there known instances of people downloading malicious Android software apps with background services that can somehow programatically attempt to login to my app's login or registration pages?  How does that work exactly - all in the background somehow?  Doesn't Android have a bit of a security sandbox that would prevent this anyway?

Most public/prominent apps don't seem to be employing this kind of technology already. Are they just taking a calculated risk that this kind of security is less needed compared to a website on the Internet?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: It's all about security of a mobile API. Without captacha it's easy to register many users and send a lot of spam messages

Comment: By "mobile API", I gather that refers to hardening the security around the, in my case, REST calls from my native Android app back to the host servers housing centralized business logic and database access - ?  If so, I have taken steps there, but that security hardening seems quite separate from the UI-focused "reCaptcha" solution.